# I get this error "JSON path Source doesn't match." when I try to compare response value and entered value

Tags: java, json

Below is the way I compare but show exception

```
.then()
    .statusCode(200)
    .body("Source",equalTo("whatsapp"))
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
> JSON path Source doesn't match.
> Expected: whatsapp
> Actual: null

Can anybody help me resolve?

Expecting it to compare and result should be according to it.